# Inserting UI into R shiny moduleServer

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, module, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to allow the user to add successive UI output seen in **server_module2** from another module (ui_module1).  So, when they hit the button, they will see 3 UI objects:  textOutput, sliderInput, textInput.  My code below stops at outputting the UI object.  If I don't wrap it in the 1st module, it works fine.

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

ui_module2 = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("finalOut"))
  
}

server_module2 = function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 output$finalOut = renderUI({
                   ns = session$ns
                   textOutput(p(style = "color: red", paste0("Package Num:", id, sep = "-")))
                   sliderInput("n", "N", 1, 1000, 500)
                   textInput("label", "Label")
                 })
               })
}

ui_module1 = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  actionBttn(ns("actionbutton1"), "Press Button For New UI")
}

server_module1 = function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 observeEvent(input$actionbutton1, {
                   i =  sprintf('%04d', input$actionbutton1)
                   id = sprintf('static%s', i)
                   
                   print(id)
                   
                   insertUI(selector = "#actionbutton1",
                            where = "afterEnd",
                            ui = ui_module2(id))
                   
                   server_module2(id)
                 })
               })
}


ui = fluidPage(ui_module1("opt)"))


server = function(input, output, session) {
  server_module1("opt)")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the working code. A lot you need to notice. Here are some key points.

1. Remember to add `ns` for all modules.
2. `renderUI` only returns one object, if you want to return more than one components, use `tagList` or `div`.
3. `insertUI` selector inside module also needs to add `ns`.

Check the code yourself for minor bugs.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

ui_module2 = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("finalOut"))
}

server_module2 = function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 output$finalOut = renderUI({
                   ns = session$ns
                   div(
                     # not sure what you want with next line, commented, fix your own
                     # textOutput(p(style = "color: red", paste0("Package Num:", id, sep = "-"))),
                     sliderInput(ns("n"), "N", 1, 1000, 500),
                     textInput(ns("label"), "Label")
                   )
                 })
               })
}

ui_module1 = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  actionBttn(ns("actionbutton1"), "Press Button For New UI")
}

server_module1 = function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 ns <- session$ns
                 observeEvent(input$actionbutton1, {
                   i =  sprintf('%04d', input$actionbutton1)
                   id = sprintf('static%s', i)
                   
                   print(id)
                   
                   insertUI(selector = paste0("#", ns("actionbutton1")),
                            where = "afterEnd",
                            immediate = TRUE,
                            ui = ui_module2(ns(id)))
                   server_module2(id)
                 })
               })
}


ui = fluidPage(ui_module1("opt"))


server = function(input, output, session) {
  server_module1("opt")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

##### understand how it works

This case is an example of nested modules. To understand this, you need to know how `ns` namespace works in Shiny.
As Shiny's official document, they tell you that you need to add `ns(id)` on the module UI and you don't need to do so for the module server, but they didn't tell you why.

When you call the `moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {...})`, the session here is different than your top-level session. If you check the session here, it's a `session_proxy` class object, no longer the `ShinySession` class object. This is how shiny internally knows how expressions under `moduleServer` are inside the module. When you call `input`, `output`, `renderXX`, `updateXX` methods under the module scope, it will first query the `session` object, and if it is `session_proxy`, call the `session$ns` to attach namespace first. This is why you don't need to add `ns()` on the server, shiny did it for you.

Ok, let's go back to the nested module problem. Let's see what's namespace on both UI and server with this simple example. All it does is print out the namespace on UI and server.

```r
library(shiny)

uiMod2 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(id = ns(""))
}

serverMod2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
   function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      print(ns(""))
   })
}

uiMod1 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    div(id = ns("")),
    uiMod2(ns("level2"))
  )
 
}

serverMod1 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
   function(input, output, session) {
     ns <- session$ns
     print(ns(""))
     serverMod2("level2")
   })
}

ui <- fluidPage(uiMod1("level1"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {serverMod1("level1")}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Results UI

[image]

Server

```r
[1] "level1-"
[1] "level1-level2-"
```

See the difference? I didn't call `ns` for second-level server, only `serverMod2("level2")`, but the namespace is automatically attached for me. However, shiny doesn't know to apply this to the UI, so I have to use `uiMod2(ns("level2"))`.

The reason why shiny doesn't know is all about `session`. When you create a module, you need to pass `function(input, output, session)`, and when you create nested modules, this `session` for the second level module is not the `ShinySession`, but a `session_proxy`, so parent namespace(s) will be appended automatically.

Things are different with UI. Normally When you create module UI like `uiMod2 <- function(id) ...`, you don't pass the session object, so it doesn't know what namespace to inherit.

Comment: I noticed that `ui = ui_module2(ns(id)))` is using ns, but `server_module2(id)` uses id only.  What's going on there?  It is the only combination that works. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: thank you!!!!  that answered my question.  though I'd also like to know jpdugo17's question.

Comment: @jpdugo17 see my edits.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thank you very much for sharing it.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to add a removeUI action button within each individual created UI element and remove both the UI and its contents?

Comment: observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, '-remove.button')]],{
                     print("removal button working")
                     removeUI(selector = sprintf('#%s', id))
                   })

Comment: the above doesn't work.  i tried with and without the ns but doesn't seem like you'd need ns(id) in the removeUI

Comment: I got it to work by letting the selector = paste0("#",ns(paste0(id,"-finalOut"))).   I don't find this a very elegant way of removing the UI.  And it doesn't remove the contents.